# How to handle no unique mode; found 2 equally common values in below function

Tags: python, mode

Here is the snippet of my function used to find mode.

```
import statistics 
unique = numpy.unique(aggr_group)
x = numpy.zeros(shape=(unique.size))
for i in range(0, unique.size):
    x[i] = statistics.mode(val[aggr_group==unique[i]])
```

However, can anyone let me know how can i handle "no unique mode; found 2 equally common value" situation here? I tried multiple options, but didn't work. Can anyone suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

The following code group the data by column 1, and find **first** mode in terms of column 0 in each group

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter


data = np.array([[115, 26925055],
        [115, 26925055],
        [115, 26925055],
        [115, 26925055],
        [114, 26925055],
        [115, 26925055],
        [115, 26925055],
        [114, 26925055],
        [115, 26925055],
        [84, 25471149],
        [111, 25471149],
        [84, 25471149],
        [84, 25471149],
        [84, 25471149],
        [84, 25471149],
        [111, 25471149],
        [111, 25471149],
        [111, 25471149],
        [84, 25471149]])
# ans = [[115, 26925055], [84, 25471149]]


def get_first_mode(a):
    c = Counter(a)  
    mode_count = max(c.values())
    mode = {key for key, count in c.items() if count == mode_count}
    first_mode = next(x for x in a if x in mode)
    return first_mode

col0 = data[:, 0]
col1 = data[:, 1]

ans = []
for v in np.unique(col1):
    mode = get_first_mode(col0[col1 == v])
    print((mode, v))
    ans.append((mode, v))
```

Here is another function for getting all modes

```
def get_all_modes(a):
    c = Counter(a)  
    mode_count = max(c.values())
    mode = {key for key, count in c.items() if count == mode_count}
    return mode
```

Comment: thanks! But i was looking to print first value if there is a tie. Like here in above example only 1.

Comment: @SreejithSharma Edited!

Comment: this works perfectly. but i need to handle one more condition, if there is a tie then first else both.

Comment: @SreejithSharma Could you elaborate on tie? If there is no tie why there is a 'both' to be considered?

Comment: here am using this function within a DB which supports python, so here if i need to find mode of two difference occurrence of column values, eventually it should return me 2 values finding model of those two arrays and with each array it will return me values. For say, i need to pass 2 array and return mode from both. hope this is clear.

Comment: that's why i was using numpy to handle N-dim

Comment: @SreejithSharma Could you provide a small sample input and desired output

Comment: Input 2 columns

Col1 Col2
115 26925055
115 26925055
115 26925055
115 26925055
114 26925055
115 26925055
115 26925055
114 26925055
115 26925055
84 25471149
111 25471149
84 25471149
84 25471149
84 25471149
84 25471149
111 25471149
111 25471149
111 25471149
84 25471149

Output
115 26925055
84 25471149

Comment: @SreejithSharma I don't find any tie here :(

Comment: no tie here. but i just gave you an sample data where 2 dim kind structure so it will return me 2 modes. There can be tie within column value for say with 26925055, then this senario also should be handled along with 2 modes from n-array.

Comment: @SreejithSharma What is 2 modes? The 2 most frequent pairs of element?

Comment: i mean, within each value of column 2 i need to find mode. So for 26925055 and 25471149 i will be getting mode values. which will make 115 and 84 in this example.

Comment: @SreejithSharma Edited to find "group the data by column 1, and find first mode in terms of column 0 in each group"

Comment: here is what am trying, not working. not sure am doing something terribly wrong.